# Add attribute to all textboxes in the site

Tags: 7, theming, forms

The question is simple , in my theme I want to apply an attribute to all textboxes in whole forms . I know how to add an attribute to an specific element in drupal using hook_form_alter , but it is too time consuming for lots of elements , so I'm eager to see if there is an easier way to do that.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use form_alter type of hooks, I would do it like this:

```
<?php

function somemodule_preprocess_textfield(&$variables) {
  $variables['element']['#attributes']['custom_attr'] = 'somevalue';    
}
```

You can replace _textfield with _textarea, I don't know what you mean by textbox :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7) for this. The following will add the "my-class" class to all textfields:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter().
 */
function test_field_widget_text_textfield_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  $element['value']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-class';
}
```